# What is the `ucond` process state?

Tags: process, freebsd

When debugging a program I saw that `top -U username` showed the following:

```
39769 eigenein       107  98    0   179M 38448K ucond  19   0:00  0.00% program
```

What does it mean that a process in the `ucond` state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ucond` indicates that the process has a thread that is waiting for a userland [condition variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29#Waiting_and_signaling).